# Euler's Method code on Mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve problem a) from the image. [Full Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NWY3.png).
So far I have this code on Mathematica:

```
h = 0.1;

t0=1;

y0 = 0;

M=Floor[0.2/h];

Y = RecurrenceTable[{y[n]==y[n-1]+h*((3*(h*(n))^2)/(3*(y[n])^2-4)),

y[1]==y0},y,{n,1,M}]

Y[[M]]
```

The value I got(-0.00300002) is not the same as the answer in the book(-0.166134). I can't see where I'm messing up on if I'm referring to the formula 1=0+ℎ(1,1)

Thanks!

Comment: Never post unsearchable words or equations.  Always show courtesy and typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: @get264: Are you aware of the Mathematica Stack Exchange and postings like https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41783/use-euler-method-to-solve-differential-equation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing the $t$ value. You can also clean up your code a bit. Denote $y'= f(t,y)$. Then

```
f[t_, y_] := 3 t^2/(3 y^2 - 4);

h = 0.1;
{t0, y0} = {1, 0};
table = RecurrenceTable[{
    y[n + 1] == y[n] + h*f[t[n], y[n]],
    t[n + 1] == t[n] + h,
    t[0] == t0,
    y[0] == y0
},
{t, y},
{n, 0, 8}
];
table
```

From this outputted table, it should be easy to see the $y(t)$ value for  $t= 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8$. Notice you can also easily change your $h$ and $f(t,y)$ if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence (for $y'=f(x,y)$) is
$$
y_n=y_{n-1}+hf(x_{n-1},y_{n-1}), \ x_n=x_{n-1}+h,
$$
i.e. you need to evaluate the derivative at $(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})$ to make the step to $(x_n,y_n)$.  You might want to draw a picture of what's going on.